# React Native - Remove item once while exist

Tags: arrays, react-native

I'm trying to remove item while it's exist in compared Array, but  for some reason when i have two Strings that are same on array it's removing these both items, any solution for that?

example:

```
["I'm", "going", "to", "go" ,"to", "London"]
```

```
  //Get selected value
  const handleSelected = (e) => {
    setReceivedItems(e);
  };

  //Update selected data at first render
  useEffect(() => {
    setNewItems((newItem) => [...newItem, receivedItems]);
    // Speech.speak(receivedItems);
  }, [receivedItems]);

  const deleteWord = (receivedItem) => {
    setNewItems((data) => data.filter((item) => item !== receivedItem));
  };

Return (

<View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      flexWrap: 'wrap',
                      marginBottom: 40,
                      width: '100%',
                    }}
                    key={i}
                  >
                    {enItems.enWordR?.map((enWordR, i) => (
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        key={i}
                        onPress={handleSelected.bind(this, enWordR)}
                        style={[
                          newItems.find((item) => item === enWordR)
                            ? styles.hideItem
                            : styles.showItem,
                        ]}
                      >
                        <Button
                          title={enWordR}
                          btnStyle={[styles.itemButton]}
                          btnWrapperStyle={[styles.itemBtnWrapper]}
                          labelStyle={styles.itemBtnLabel}
                        />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    ))}
                  </View>
>
)
```

So, in above example both "to" will be hidden

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are using map or any looping function.

For instance,

```
arr.map((item, index) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => RemoveItem(index)} >{item}</TouchableOpacity>
const RemoveItem = (index) => { 
var arrclone = [...arr]; arrclone = arrclone.splice(index,1); setarr(arrclone);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Usama, but i'm receiving Event value with onPress

Comment: Why you are receiving event value as we are not passing any event. Did you copy the same code. I pasted

Comment: I mean my current code, i'm receiving e.value from user onPress, how could i pass Index with it?

Comment: Check TouchableOpacity is imported from react-native and confirm me you are doing it on react native.

Please share the complete code

Comment: Check now, updated code